# What software is used to make these X-bar trees?

Tags: syntax-trees, parsing, trees

I'm looking for software for illustrating tree diagrams am wondering whether anyone knows which was used to create the one in the post linked below.

I have tried messaging the author, but had no luck and was wondering whether someone recognized the application used or maybe has suggestions for others.

Post: [Analyzing negation with a syntactic tree](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/19006/analyzing-negation-with-a-syntactic-tree?answertab=active#tab-top)

Example tree:

[image]

Comment: Looking at the fonts, I think it is LaTeX, but I don't know the additional package used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not concerned with linguistics.

Comment: Allthough the question is probably also on-topic on [tex.se] (with some reformuöation, like what LaTeX package is used to generate the trees) I voted to leave it open because the answer might be relevant to linguists and readers of this stackexchange.

Comment: @WiccanKarnak: In what way do you see this as unrelated to linguistics? Surely, it must be allowed to share resources for linguistic description?

Comment: @luhausler if you look at it without the syntax tree part, it's just a *what font is this* question. The syntax tree part is just there as an example. It would certainly *help* linguists , but then what about *identifications* which as one time reads can make the linguist aware/ give him the knowledge of yet another script, which he/she can use inthe future. (I am not implying that identifications should be on topic, just that everything that helps linguists is not on topic here)

Comment: In my experience, I think this is important, working on syntax requires sharp reasoning and exploring a wide range of accounts of data, this would be more, or bit, easy, and facile, if there exists such a software that parses sentences. I, currently, work only with microsoft word, and it takes me at least 30 minutes to draw a tree of a transitive structure in a light v diagram.. Please consider this important.. thank you.

Comment: @WiccanKarnak: I think there has been a misunderstanding. My inquiry is not for the font used, but for the software used to illustrate and build tree diagrams.

Comment: @TarikLahyany: Agreed. I’m looking specifically for software to illustrate (i.e. construct) trees, not automatic parsing.

Comment: The one I used is called 'Syntax tree editor' with a green tree as its icon. I no longer use it now, because I have parsing related to roots and morphophonological issues in the same tree, it doesn't prove itself useful at this level, so I'm still looking :)

Comment: ok so the rewording and the comments helped, upvoted the question, trying to retract close vote and delete comment but that won't happen,

Comment: "Questions requesting to make syntax trees are not within the scope defined in the help center. For any doubt, please ask on Meta."

Comment: @NickNicholas I believe that refers to "can you please draw a syntax tree for this sentence" (apparently a common homework assignments in some curricula) rather than "I can produce a syntax tree but I want a tool to help me make it production quality".

Comment: The linked answer is by one of the site's moderators so it is not unlikely that they are simply busy with other things.

Comment: Thanks for your input, WiccanKarnak. Will keep it in mind for future posts. 
@NickNicholas: At no point am I requesting the drawing of a syntax tree, tripleee is correct.

Comment: Here's one I wrote a long time ago: https://ctan.org/pkg/gl-tree  It works on screen or for printing to a Postscript printer.

Comment: Author of the screenshotted post here -- I am only now seeing this question, but yes, this was done with LaTeX and tix-qtree, as layed out nicely in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is almost certainly done with [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX), or one of its friends, and the [tikz-qtree](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-qtree) package. It is an improvement of the [qtree](https://ctan.org/pkg/qtree) package with nicer node placement. If you are not familiar with LaTeX, and want to learn more, [this Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Linguistics#Syntactic_trees) might help (link is to the page about linguistics, but the book is in general about LaTeX). Both tikz-qtree and qtree have a quite extensive manual.

Below is LaTeX code using the tikz-qtree package to draw your tree. The only difference with the original seems to be that the bar over the T and the v is less bold. Perhaps this was done with something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66537/making-hats-and-other-accents-bold), but I cannot get it to look exactly the same.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}

\Tree [.TP
    [.NP Jane$_i$ ]
    [.\=T
        [.T did T(past) ]
        [.NegP
            [.Neg not ]
            [.vP
                [.NP t$_i$ ]
                [.\=v v [.VP \edge[roof]; {go to school} ] ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

\end{document}
```

[image]

An older version of this answer just used the qtree package (instead of tikz-qtree) and draws something that looks like your tree. The only trick we need is to use `array` and `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}`, because otherwise the bar over the T is touched by the edge. The differences with the original:

- The overbar is less bold;
- in the original, nodes on one level are on the same height (e.g. Jane<sub>*i*</sub> and T and NegP);
- qtree does not consider text height to draw edges, so there is a lot of space from the edge to the text of the v node at the very bottom (because it has no capital); in the original this looks better.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{document}

\Tree [.TP
    [.NP Jane_i ]
    [.\=T
        [.T did T(past) ]
        [.NegP
            [.Neg not ]
            [.vP
                [.NP t_i ]
                [.\=v v \qroof{go to school}.VP ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Author of the screenshotted post here -- yes, this is precisely how it was done, LaTeX with tikz-qtree. IIRC I did the bars with `\overline{\text{T}}`, though `\={T}` is simpler.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a VISUAL editor for Syntactic Trees, I think [TreeForm](https://sourceforge.net/projects/treeform/) could be a solution for you. The software is a specific solution for drawing Trees in a WYSIWYG approach. It has "templates" for X-Bar 3 levels (XP-X'-X), adding adjuncts/complements, etc, all with one click and some typing (actually, not literally a click, you drag and drop models/phrases and add them to the tree).

The software has several possible improvements and limitations, but it works. I have actually found this thread while looking for a better solution, but meanwhile it's the best thing I know about (considering my preference for a visual editor).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: How so? It says: "I'm looking for software for illustrating tree diagrams [...]". Isn't that what I just presented, @curiousdannii ???

Comment: @curiousdannii take a look at this comment from the same person: 
"Agreed. I’m looking specifically for software to illustrate (i.e. construct) trees, not automatic parsing". – luhausler Apr 11 '18 at 21:12

Comment: Please, notice he says he's looking "for software to illustrate", not "for the software which illustrated".