# Verbose tree diagram drawer for MP

Tags: syntax-trees

Is there any tree diagram drawer software for English sentences which shows all features of nodes, all movements (and other things which happen like feature checking by c-command)?

Comment: See also this question and its answers: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/27660/what-software-is-used-to-make-these-x-bar-trees